# numpy NaN not always recognized

Tags: python, numpy, nan

This puzzles me:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 3])  # an array with a nan
print(np.isnan(a)[2])            # it truly is a nan
print(a[2])                      # it quacks like a nan
print(np.nan is np.nan)          # nan's can be compared
print(a[2] is np.nan)            # But then, this isn't a nan after all!!??
```

Output:

```
True
nan
True
False
```

I know we're not allowed to compare nan's with `==`, but with `is` should be allowed? After all it works when comparing nan to itself?

Comment: I don't fully understand either, but this observation may help: Python `float`s can actually be `nan` too. You can construct one via `float("nan")`. But it seems to make a new object. `float("nan") is float("nan")` returns `False`.

Comment: In general, `is` and `==` are completely unrelated operations. Nan is not a singleton

Comment: `is` should _not_ be allowed. It's only allowed for things that are explicitly defined to be singletons (like `None`), or for instances of your own types that you created manually so you know whether they're identical. Neither one is true here. It's perfectly valid for `x is y` to be true for two separate NaN values, or for it to be false; your code cannot rely on either. It may be _interesting_ learning why it is and isn't true for different cases (depending on your numpy and Python versions), but it's not _useful_ except in getting to know Python internals better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This isn't so much a question about the Python `is` operator, as about what indexing, or unboxing, an element of an array does:

```
In [363]: a = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 3])

In [364]: a[2]
Out[364]: nan

In [365]: type(a[2])
Out[365]: numpy.float64

In [366]: a[2] is a[2]
Out[366]: False
```

`a[2]` doesn't simply return `nan`.  It returns a `np.float64` object whose values is `np.nan`.  Another `a[2]` will produce another `np.float64` object.  Two such objects don't match in the `is` sense.  That's true for any array element, not just `nan` values.

Since `==` doesn't work for `nan`, we are stuck with using the `np.isnan` function.

`np.nan` is a unique `float` object (in this session), but `a[2]` is not set to that object.

If the array was defined as an object type:

```
In [376]: b = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 3], object)

In [377]: b[2] is np.nan
Out[377]: True
```

here the `is` is True - because `b` contains pointers to objects that already exist in memory, including the `np.nan` object.  Same would be true for a list constructed like that.

Comment: To be clear, `type(np.nan)` → `float`, the builtin. Is it worth editing that in, or is there more nuance to it? I'm not a NumPy expert.

Answer (score 7):

First, at least in NumPy 1.15, `np.nan` happens to be a special singleton, meaning that whenever NumPy has to give you a NaN value of type `float`, it tries to give you the same `np.nan` value.

But this is not documented anywhere, or guaranteed to be true across versions.

This fits into the larger class of values that may or may not be singletons, as an implementation detail.

As a general rule, if your code relies on two equal values of an immutable type being identical or not being identical, your code is wrong.

Here are some examples from a default build of CPython 3.7:

```
>>> a, b = 200, 201
>>> a is b-1
True
>>> a, b = 300, 301
>>> a is b-1
False
>>> 301-1 is 300
True
>>> math.nan is math.nan
True
>>> float('nan') is math.nan
False
>>> float('nan') is float('nan')
False
```

You *can* learn all of the rules that make all of these things come out that way, but they could all change in a different Python implementation, or in version 3.8, or even in 3.7 built with custom configure options. So, just never use `1` or `math.nan` or `np.nan` or `''` with `is`; only use it for objects that are specifically documented to be singletons (like `None`—or instances of your own types, of course).

---

Second, when you index a numpy array, it has to "unbox" the value by constructing a scalar, of a type appropriate to the array's `dtype`. For a `dtype=float64` array, the scalar value it constructs is a `np.float64`.

So, `a[2]` is guaranteed to be a `np.float64`.

But `np.nan` is not an `np.float64`, it's a `float`.

So, there's no way NumPy can give you `np.nan` when you ask for `a[2]`. Instead, it gives you an `np.float64` with a NaN value.

---

OK, so that's why `a[2] is np.nan` is always False. But why is `a[2] is a[2]` also usually false?

As I mentioned above, NumPy tries to give you `np.nan` whenever it needs to give you a `float` NaN. But—at least in 1.15—it doesn't have any special singleton value to provide whenever it needs to give you a `np.float64` NaN. There's no reason it *couldn't*, but nobody bothered to write such code, because it shouldn't matter either way to any properly-written app.

So, each time you unbox the value in `a[2]` into a scalar `np.float64`, it gives you a new NaN-valued `np.float64`.

But why isn't this the same as `301-1 is 300`? Well, the reason that works is that the compiler is allowed to fold constants of known immutable type with equal values, and CPython does exactly that, for simple cases, within each compilation unit. But two NaN values aren't equal; a NaN value isn't even equal to itself. So, it can't be constant-folded.

(If you're wondering what happens if you create an array with an int dtype and store small values in it and check whether they get merged into the small-int singletons—try it and see.)

---

And of course this is why `isnan` exists in the first place. You can't test for NaN with equality (because NaN values are not equal to anything, even themselves), you can't test for NaN with identity (for all of the reasons described above), so you need a function to test for them.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
In [1]: type(a[2])
Out[1]: numpy.float64

In [2]: type(numpy.nan)
Out[2]: float
```

and also

```
In [3]: id(a[2])
Out[3]: 4419858888

In [4]: id(np.nan)
Out[4]: 4326468200
```

They're not the same

Comment: I think this much was obvious. `id != id` is pretty much a synonym for `is` being `False`. The question is why indexing yields a different object.