# Cannot detect nan value in a list even though datatype is logically correct

Tags: python, numpy

I called in list within a list created from a Custom Dataset using pytorch.

```
In [1]: sample[1][1]
Out[1]: [0.7, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

I want to check whether there is a nan value within a list. I tried

```
In [2]: np.nan in sample[1][1]
Out[2]: False
```

But it is returning a False output. Checking one of the elements, I found out that:

```
In [3]: sample[1][1][4] == np.nan
Out[3]: False
```

Supposedly, it must be true because checking its type prompts me with:

```
In [4]: type(sample[1][1][4])
Out[4]: numpy.float64
```

Need help to see where I went wrong. I want that list to return True because it contains a nan. Any leads will help

Comment: you should use ```np.isnan(sample)```

Comment: What's the type of `sample[1][1]`?. This wouldn't happen with a list.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [np.isnan](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) for that, as you can see here:

```
In [5]: np.nan==np.nan
Out[5]: False

In [6]: np.isnan(np.nan)
Out[6]: True
```

The reason is a little abstruse but the takehome is to use np.isnan for the test.
For your particular case you can do

```
any([np.isnan(i) for i in sample[1][1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

From my given:

```
In [1]: sample[1][1]
Out[1]: [0.7, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

I tried a workaround. Thanks to the idea of `np.isnan()`. Added the boolean values in the array and if its greater than 0 then it must have a nan.

```
In [2]: np.isnan(sample[1][1])
Out[2]: array([False, True, True, True, True])
```

```
In [3]: np.isnan(sample[1][1]).sum()
Out[3]: 4
In [4]: np.isnan(sample[1][1]).sum()>0
Out[3]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd issue somehow related to the implementation of the `in` operator for your `sample[1][1]` object.

The solution is to cast to a list:

```
In [5]: np.nan in list(sample[1][1])
Out[5]: True
```

EDIT: This is the quick and dirty way. This solution relies on `(np.nan is np.nan) == True`. However, this is not guaranteed to be true in all cases (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123892/numpy-nan-not-always-recognized)). So it's best to stick to a construct that involves `np.isnan(x)` such as given in a few other answers.